# Python Error "IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Tags: python, list, for-loop, index-error

I'm having trouble with my code and would appreciate any comments related.
My problem is that I can't call elements from a list although it seems to me the list is big enough. The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BrownM.py", line 126, in <module>
    optim1(pbias,x,i,nbias,stock1,cash1)
  File "BrownM.py", line 88, in optim1
    win1[i] = cash1[i] - cash1[i-1]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I don't really understand where is the problem. Maybe I'm using ".append" too much?

The code is something like:

```
import numpy as np

p0 = []
p0.append(0)
p0[0]=1000.00

ts=10               

dx = 1.0
x = np.random.uniform(0.0,dx)
pbias= np.random.uniform(1.0, 50.0)
nbias= np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)

cash1 = []
cash1.append(1)
cash1[0]=100000.0
cash4 = []
cash4.append(1)
cash4[0]=100000.0

stock1=0
stock4=0

win1 = []
win4 = []

def optim1(pbias,x,i,nbias, stock1,cash1):

    if p0[i] <= p0[i-1] + pbias*x :
        stock1= stock1 + 1
        cash1[i] = cash1[i-1] - p0[i]


    elif p0[i] > p0[i-1] + pbias*x :
        if stock1 > 0:
            stock1 = stock1-1
            cash1[i] = cash1[i-1] + p0[i]

    win1[i] = cash1[i] - cash1[i-1]


def pesim1(pbias,x,i,nbias, stock4,cash4):

    if p0[i] < p0[i-1] - nbias*x :
        stock4= stock4 + 1
        cash4[i] = cash4[i-1] - p0[i]

    elif p0[i] >= p0[i-1] - pbias*x:
        if stock4 > 0:
            stock4 = stock4-1
            cash4[i] = cash4[i-1] + p0[i]

    win4[i] = cash4[i] - cash4[i-1]


for i in range(1,ts):
    p0.append(i)
    p0[i] = p0[i-1]

    cash1.append(i)
    win1.append(i)
    cash4.append(i)
    win4.append(i)

    optim1(pbias,x,i,nbias,stock1,cash1)
    pesim1(pbias,x,i,nbias,stock4,cash4)
```

So the code shouldn't print anything yet, but when running it throws the error.

Thanks again for any help or comments you can give me

Comment: When you append, you're adding the value in the parentheses to the end of that list. I'd add print statements to your code so you can see what's happening, I think it will clear up a lot.

Comment: It did help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

win1 isn't big enough. In your first iteration of `for i in range(1,ts)` you're accessing it's 1 position index, `win1[1]`, but win1's length is only 1 thus it only has a 0 position index, `win1[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. I was thinking  the value in ".append(#)" meant the space in the list added so i was using it incorrectly.